# Access remote folder via an intermmediate machine on a graphical file manager

Tags: ssh, sftp, remote-access

I want to access a remote folder on a server B that is accessible only via a server A. I have accounts on both machines.

To access a terminal on B i would first connect to A via ssh, and then hop to B.
To use a port on B I would do the same, establishing a port mapping via ssh tunneling.

But what can I do to access a folder on B from a graphical file manager, like dolphin, using a protocol like fish? How can I establish the intermmediate connection?

I have tried the indirect way of creating a tunnel from `localhost:port` to the intermmediate machine, and from there to the target machine, and connect to `fish://localhost:port` on the file manager, but keep getting connection refused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using standard `sshfs` if you configure the intermediate machine as a proxy in your client configuration (default location is `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host <remote>
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy
Host proxy
  Hostname <real-proxy>
```

where `<remote>` is the hostname / IP address of the remote machine (`%h` will be replaced by it later). `<real-proxy>` is the hostname / IP address of the intermediate machine.

Then you can mount your remote filesystem locally and access it using whatever graphical file manager you like:

```
sshfs <remote>:/remote/path /mnt/mountpoint
```

Comment: Thanks! I already have such an ssh config file, and turns out I can directly enter fish://remote on the dolphin file manager (which must use sshfs on the background).